# How Exactly Current Flow Through a Capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, current

Capacitors behaving as an open circuits, How can we understand the concept of the Electrons flowing through a capacitors.

[image: Current Displacement Through a Capacitor circuits]

Comment: Duplicates: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18301/2028 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/76767/2028

Comment: Duplicate? While I might agree since its all related to capacitors in this tag so in one way or another answers or questions on this tag will always have conflict since they are surrounding one component a capacitor,  I did found some answers from stevenvh  on the other question u suggested. But the emphasis here is this question point out at how exactly current flow through a capacitor.

Comment: You should probably edit it to make it more distinct from the other question. I agree none of those answers explain how current flows through a capacitor, but it's not clear from your question that that's what you're looking for. Also, look up [displacement current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [EEVblog #486 – Does Current Flow Through A Capacitor?](http://www.eevblog.com/2013/06/21/eevblog-486-does-current-flow-through-a-capacitor/)

Electrons do not leap from one capacitor plate to the other but whilst the capacitor is charging or discharging as many electrons leave one terminal as arrive at the other, they are not the same electrons but for all practical purposes you can say that changing currents flow through a capacitor.

Comment: Good Link to the video, In a practical way current does flow through the Capacitor, the Changing current as you mentioned, the whole concept of Electronics is based on the displacement of electrons, through diverse electronics components forming an Electronics circuit or Network. A capacitor looking more like an open circuit, can`t be compare with a switch that can`t pass anything when open.

Comment: @mChad In reality, depending on how a switch is built, it will actually look like a capacitor. Consider a small SPST switch with contacts in very close proximity. That will have a capacitance between the pole and the throw.